# Solace Container jar missing in mvn repository

Tags: maven, testcontainers, solace

It seems like the jar testcontainers for solace

`https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/solace/`

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
   <artifactId>solace</artifactId>
   <version>1.17.6</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

does not exists in `https://mvnrepository.com/`

Answer (score 1):

The Solace module was added to testcontainers quite recently (see [this PR](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/pull/6583)), but the [1.17.6 release](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/releases/tag/1.17.6) (the latest at the time of writing) was created last year. So the module will appear in maven central only with the next testcontainers release.